# Deploying ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application on IIS Container Results in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .net, docker, iis

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application on an IIS container, using the base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis. Here are the steps I've taken:

Removed the contents of the /inetpub/wwwroot directory.
Copied the contents of my application's publish directory into /inetpub/wwwroot.
However, when I try to access the application, I'm encountering a "500 Internal Server Error" with the message "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

I suspect there might be an issue with the IIS configuration or my deployment process. Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Removing existing content in /inetpub/wwwroot before deploying.
Copying the contents of the publish directory into /inetpub/wwwroot.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this "500 Internal Server Error" issue when deploying an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application on an IIS container.

What I am expecting is when I access my application it should open without throwing any errors.

Additional Details:

My ASP.NET Core web application is built on .NET Core 3.1.
I'm using the mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis base image.
I've checked the event logs, but they don't provide specific information about the error.
Are there any specific IIS configurations or settings I should be aware of when deploying an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application?

Comment: Please study what is the right way https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile.windowsservercore-iis The sample has been there for years.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lex linked a great [sample](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile.windowsservercore-iis) for installing ASP.NET Core into the image (which is what you are missing). However, that sample used .NET 8. For you case you'll need to instead install the ASP.NET 3.1 host ([Download link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.32-windows-hosting-bundle-installer))